# how to change json key values?

Tags: php, json

I have the following json data that is pulled from an sql database and encoded.
I want to change the value of day so that it is the actual day , ie 0 = Monday 6 = Sunday. Is there any way to do this. Sorry im v new to coding

```
[{"Day":"0","Hour":"1","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"0","Hour":"3","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"0","Hour":"7","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"1","Subject":"Physics"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"5","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"9","Subject":"Physics"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"11","Subject":"Physics"},
{"Day":"2","Hour":"1","Subject":"Computing"}]
```

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: I assume you use PHP?

Comment: Yes sorry php @131

Comment: so instead of `"Day":"0"` you want it to be `"Day":"Monday"`, right?

Comment: @131 correct, It is stored in the database as 0 through 7 but I want to display it in a table as monday through sunday so I need to change those values.

Comment: what tool, language or framework would you like to use to change it? JSON is just a String formatted in JSON standard. BTW: does your week has 8 days? from 0 to 7?

Comment: @vadim It was meant to say 0-6 sry, im not sure, at the moment im pulling it from the database encoding it and then using the encoded json with jquery and a library called pivottable to make a table. I need to change the value before using it in pivotable but Im not sure if you would do this in php or if you can simply edit the json directly. Php is probably what your asking tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for:

```
<?php
$json='[{"Day":"0","Hour":"1","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"0","Hour":"3","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"0","Hour":"7","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"1","Subject":"Physics"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"5","Subject":"Computing"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"9","Subject":"Physics"},
{"Day":"1","Hour":"11","Subject":"Physics"},
{"Day":"2","Hour":"1","Subject":"Computing"}]';
$transform=array(
    0=>"Monday",
    1=>"Tuesday",
    2=>"Wednesday",
    3=>"Thursday",
    4=>"Friday",
    5=>"Saturday",
    6=>"Sunday"
);

$json=json_decode($json);
foreach($json as $key) $key->Day=$transform[$key->Day];
echo "<pre><h2>";
echo print_r($json);
?>
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Hour] => 1
            [Subject] => Computing
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Hour] => 3
            [Subject] => Computing
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Monday
            [Hour] => 7
            [Subject] => Computing
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Tuesday
            [Hour] => 1
            [Subject] => Physics
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Tuesday
            [Hour] => 5
            [Subject] => Computing
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Tuesday
            [Hour] => 9
            [Subject] => Physics
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Tuesday
            [Hour] => 11
            [Subject] => Physics
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Day] => Wednesday
            [Hour] => 1
            [Subject] => Computing
        )

)
```

Comment: No problem mate

Answer (score 2):

OK whatever language you will use you need to make a code to follow pseudo code below:

your JSON text is an Array of objects. Let's call what you got jsonArray and each object in it jsonElement:

```
for each jsonElement in jsonArray loop
   case (jsonElement.Day)
    when 0: assign jsonElement.Day to "Moday"        
    when 1: assign jsonElement.Day to "Tuesday"
    ...
    when 6: assign jsonElement.Day to "Sunday"
end loop
```